# Spring Tool Suite fails to load driver url

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

When running the default ApplicationTest Junit in a Spring Boot application generated with Spring starter **inside the Spring Tool Suite IDE**, it fails with `Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.`

When running the same Junit test from command line with `mvn clean test`, the test is successful.

Environment

- Windows 10
- STS 4.17.2 (clean install)
- maven 3.6.3
- JDK 11
- Spring boot 2.7.10-SNAPSHOT

The application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
```

Comment: Maybe you are hitting a problem in the latest STS/Eclipse release that the application.properties file is not copied to the target directory automatically. Does it work if you execute the maven build step from within the IDE and then start the app from within the IDE?

Comment: I gave up on Eclipse based editor (STS) and switched to Intellij ... the annual cost is way less than the time I was spending troubleshooting issues that were Eclipse based.

Comment: Just for completeness, the latest release of the Spring Tools 4 distribution for Eclipse 4.18.0 includes a fixed version of the Maven integration.